# How to connect to OpenVPN with NetworkManager

Tags: linux, security, openwrt, vpn

I have installed an OpenVPN server on my OpenWrt 10.03 router [freshly flashed]: https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hRECWuf1

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf; opkg update; opkg install luci-app-openvpn openvpn openssl-util openssh-sftp-server ntpd
vim /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf # modify a few lines
[ CA_default ]
dir             = /etc/openvpn
new_certs_dir   = $dir/certs
certificate = $dir/ca.crt
private_key = $dir/ca.key

touch /etc/openvpn/index.txt; touch /etc/openvpn/serial; echo 01 > /etc/openvpn/serial
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout /etc/openvpn/ca.key -out /etc/openvpn/ca.crt -days 3650 # give a common name, like: vpnserver
openvpn --genkey --secret /etc/openvpn/ta.key
openssl req -nodes -new -keyout /etc/openvpn/server.key -out /etc/openvpn/server.csr # give a common name, like: vpnserver
mkdir -p /etc/openvpn/certs; mkdir -p /etc/openvpn/private
openssl ca -out /etc/openvpn/server.crt -in /etc/openvpn/server.csr
time openssl dhparam -out /etc/openvpn/dh1024.pem 1024 # it could take 10 minutes!

# generate certs for clients [X = client number]
openssl req -nodes -new -keyout /etc/openvpn/clientX.key -out /etc/openvpn/clientX.csr # give a common name! it will be the user name
openssl ca -out /etc/openvpn/clientX.crt -in /etc/openvpn/clientX.csr
# e.g.: 
openssl req -nodes -new -keyout /etc/openvpn/client1.key -out /etc/openvpn/client1.csr # give a common name! it will be the user name
openssl ca -out /etc/openvpn/client1.crt -in /etc/openvpn/client1.csr

vim /etc/config/openvpn
config 'openvpn' 'openvpn_server'
        option 'enable' '1'
        option 'port' '1194'
        option 'proto' 'udp'
        option 'dev' 'tap'
        option 'ca' '/etc/openvpn/ca.crt'
        option 'cert' '/etc/openvpn/server.crt'
        option 'key' '/etc/openvpn/server.key'
        option 'tls_auth' '/etc/openvpn/ta.key 0' # server: 0
        option 'dh' '/etc/openvpn/dh1024.pem'
        option 'comp_lzo' '1'
        option 'server' '10.20.30.0 255.255.255.0'
        option 'keepalive' '10 120'
        option 'persist_key' '1'
        option 'persist_tun' '1'
        option 'mute' '20'
        option 'verb' '3'
        option 'client_to_client' '1'
        list 'push' 'dhcp-option DNS 10.20.30.1'
/etc/init.d/openvpn enable
/etc/init.d/openvpn start
ifconfig -a | less
ping 10.20.30.1

# here comes the firewall part
vim /etc/config/firewall # modify it
config 'include'
        option 'path' '/etc/firewall.user'

config 'redirect'
        option 'src' 'wan'
        option 'proto' 'udp'
        option 'src_dport' '1194'
        option 'dest_port' '1194'
        option '_name' 'OpenVPN'

vim /etc/firewall.user # modify it
iptables -t nat -A prerouting_rule -i $WAN -p udp --dport 11194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A input_rule -i $WAN -p udp --dport 11194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A forwarding_rule -i tap+ -o br-lan -j ACCEPT
iptables -A forwarding_rule -i br-lan -o tap+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A input_rule -i tap+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A output_rule -o tap -j ACCEPT

/etc/init.d/firewall restart

# tar the files that goes to the client1
mkdir -p /root/client1
cp /etc/openvpn/ca.crt /root/client1/; cp /etc/openvpn/client1.crt /root/client1/; cp /etc/openvpn/client1.key /root/client1/; cp /etc/openvpn/ta.key /root/client1/
cd /root/; tar -cf client1.tar client1
```

It seems "ok".

I connect my pc to the lan port of the router, and i want to try it out. I'm using Fedora 14 with GNOME. In the NetworkManager applet i set these things: [this](http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/5266/screenshotxrg.png) and [this](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/6646/screenshot1lti.png). Ok! I try to connect, but it fails. Here are the logs: https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gv2xChxW

```
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF NetworkManager[1458]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF NetworkManager[1458]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 23552
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF NetworkManager[1458]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF NetworkManager[1458]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 1
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF NetworkManager[1458]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 3
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF NetworkManager[1458]: <info> VPN connection 'elsovpn' (Connect) reply received.
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF nm-openvpn[23554]: OpenVPN 2.1.1 i686-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] built on Jan  5 2010
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF nm-openvpn[23554]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF nm-openvpn[23554]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF nm-openvpn[23554]: Cannot load certificate file /home/g/Desktop/client1/client1.crt: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied: error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib: error:140AD002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file:system lib
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF nm-openvpn[23554]: Exiting
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF kernel: [55630.235164] type=1400 audit(1299508963.340:23608): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=23554 comm="openvpn" name="client1.crt" dev=dm-1 ino=3019385 scontext=system_u:system_r:openvpn_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF NetworkManager[1458]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF NetworkManager[1458]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 6
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF NetworkManager[1458]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF NetworkManager[1458]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF NetworkManager[1458]: <info> Policy set 'Auto Ethernet' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Mar  7 15:42:49 ASDF NetworkManager[1458]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
```

one important thing: my routers [the one with the openvpn server] ip address is 192.168.1.2, and i didn't had to write it nowhere. so how could the networkmanager applet know the ip address of my openvpn server? i think this is the problem, but i just can't find where to write 192.168.1.2

p.s.: yes, i tried to google for: "No server certificate verification method has been enabled." but i didn't find a thing, and i'm trying for hours now... :\

p.s.[again..]: yes, i tried to google for: "No server certificate verification method has been enabled." but i didn't find a thing, and i'm trying for hours now... :\

p.s.: If I do this on the router:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

and stat tcpdump, and try to connect from my pc, nothing happens!.. so the bug is in the networkmanager applet!?

again, p.s.: if I do this:

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.2 1197
Trying 192.168.1.2...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.2: Connection refused
$connbsp;
```

Are there any good howtos about setting this kind of openvpn [as in the pastebin link, on an openwrt router..]? Is it worth finding another openvpn client program? [other then the networkmanager applet]

Comment: Are you sure those pastebin snippets won't expire some time in the future? In not, just paste them here so that your post remains unseful for a long time.

Comment: tshepang - updated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So where points that address you typed in a gateway field? I've never configured OpenVPN using NetworkManager but i suppose that is the place where you should provide the address of your router.

And in your log file there is a line which says:

```
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF nm-openvpn[23554]: Cannot load certificate file /home/g/Desktop/client1/client1.crt: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied: error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib: error:140AD002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file:system lib
```

And after that:

```
Mar  7 15:42:43 ASDF kernel: [55630.235164] type=1400 audit(1299508963.340:23608): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=23554 comm="openvpn" name="client1.crt" dev=dm-1 ino=3019385 scontext=system_u:system_r:openvpn_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file
```

It looks like a SELinux related problem. SELinux denies access to your certificate file. I would search [here](http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/excerpt/selnx_1/index.html) or [here](http://tanso.net/selinux/) how to set rules for SELinux. For sure you should set read permission for certificate files to make openvpn able to read them. I don't use SELinux based system, so i can't check what rules u should use.

About telnet: In your config you set 1194 port for openvpn, but you are trying to connect on 1197 port using telnet.

Comment: yes, problem solved: i had to copy the keys/certs to the ~/.cert folder, then run a command: "restorecon -Rv ~/.cert*" - selinux was preventing the connection. and yes, i used the wrong port for telnet. now i can connect via vpn